# Cannot resolve keyword 'phone' into field django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I added a new field name phone for phone number in my registration form, but now it throws error when i submit it throws

> Cannot resolve keyword 'phone' into field. Choices are: address,
> date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff,
> is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, notifications, order,
> password, profile, user_permissions, username

this error i am using Django default usercreation forms
here is my forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{10}$', message="Inform a valid phone number.")
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, required=True,  help_text='Required. Inform a valid phone number.')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        qs = User.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(email__iexact=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError('A user with this email address already exists')
        return email
    
    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        qs = User.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(phone__iexact=phone)
        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError('A user with same phone number already exists')
        return phone
```

views.py

```
class SignUpView(View):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'register.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)

            messages.success(request, ('Please Confirm your email to complete registration.'))

            return render( request, 'activation_sent_success.html')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

any suggestion help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `phone` field:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2',)
                                    ^^^^^^
```

In your case, `fields` in `class Meta` is used to specify which fields of your `User` model will be in your form. You can omit some fields of your model with it.

Your `User` model does not have a field named `phone`. Adding this field to your model will solve your problem and do not forget executing `python manage.py makemigrations`.

If your model has this field, then you might forget applying migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: yes  i forgot that thank you